# Open file without Filename with lua skript

Tags: file, lua, filenames

Good evening,

I am currently working on a programm that takes information from a file into a Database, for testing purposes I used to open Testfiles in the classical way via IO:

```
function reader (file, delimeter)
    local f = io.open(file)
    for line in f:lines() do
        lines[count] = splitty(line, delimeter)
        count = count + 1;
    end
end
```

(this part also containes the first part of a splitter)

But in the actual environment, the database programm imediatly moves the file in another directory with a name change to, for example this:

```
$30$15$2016$09$26$13$27$24$444Z$.Pal.INV.csv
```

Now I know the directory but I can't really predict the name, so I wanted to know if there might be a way to open files without knowing their name.
(and delete them after reading them)

I had ideas to use a modified  link:

```
local inputFile = "D:\\Directory\\(*all)"
```

but it failed.

Other aviable information:
The system is until now only planned on Windows PCs.
The directory will always only contain the one file that is to ready, no other files.

Comment: I don't understand the point of the system. 1. Why can't the name be static and known. 2. What's the point in having a directory with a single file?

Comment: The core of all of this trouble is a Datastudio that is supposed to manage the whole data, from reading it out of files, over storage into databases down to deliver the requested data to the processes that need them, sadly that thing isn't anywhere near ready or intelligent designed, it is for example missing an option to customize the reading pattern (understanding what a date is, an object name usw.) and I have to fix this via workaround.
What the Database does, is renaming the file that it gets in the triggering directory while I my tool has to read it, so I need to read the renamed one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-- directory name and file name should consist of ASCII-7-bit characters only
local dir = [[C:\Temp\New Folder]]
local file = io.popen('dir /b/s/a-d "'..dir..'" 2>nul:'):read"*a":match"%C+"
if not file then
   error"No files in this directory"
end
-- print the file name of first file in the directory
print(file)  --> C:\Temp\New Folder\New Text Document.txt
```

Comment: Still providing the uninformative, short lasting answers I see xD

Comment: @warspyking - Uninformative answer?  Really?  Qui habet aures audiendi audiat.

Comment: I'm referring to the lack of explanation to help them understand how it works.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `lfs.dir` iterator from LuaFileSystem to iterate through the contents of the directory. A small example:

```
local lfs = require("lfs")

local path = "D:\\Directory\\" -- Your directory path goes here.
for filename in lfs.dir(path) do
    print(filename) -- Work with filename, i will just print it
end
```

If you keep a record of the files you will be able to know which one is the new one. If it is only one file, then it will be easier, you can just check the extension with a `string` function. From what i remember the iterator includes `..` and `.`. [lfs documentation can be found here.](https://keplerproject.github.io/luafilesystem/manual.html)

Comment: A very nice and effective way, tryed it in ZeroBraneStudio but sadly the compiler in the actual Datastudio didn't have the LuaFileSystem Library, so I had to use the other one, but if including librarys is an option this one is definetly better.